# Vue.js problem with send values in array to endpoint

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, axios

I'm just started learning Vue to finish my project. My backend is in Java Spring.
My end-point expect object with values:

```
LocalDate date;
Long buyerId;
Long supplierId;
List<OrderDetailsDto> orderDetails;
```

my object in Vue looks like:

```
order: {
          date: '',
          buyerId: 0,
          supplierId: 0,
          orderDetails: [
              {
                  quantity: 0
                  product: {
                      id: 0
                  }
              }
          ]
      }
```

and my inputs for quantity and products (just with those values is problem):

```
           <div class="form-group">
                <label>Ilość (m3)</label>
                <input type="number" id="quantity" class="form-control" v-model="order.orderDetails.quantity"/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Wybierz product</label>
                <select v-model="order.orderDetails.product">
                <option
                    v-bind:value="{id: product.id, name: product.product}"
                    v-for="product in products"
                    v-bind:key="product.id"
                >{{ product.product }}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

with that settings my request object looks like (that is console.log just before send request):

```
{__ob__: Observer}
  date: (...)
  buyerId: (...)
  supplierId: (...)
  orderDetails: Array(1)
    quantity: "22"
    product: Object
    0:
    quantity: 0
    product: Object
```

and here is the problem. Variables which I declared in Vue are at index [0] in orderDetails.
Those values above (quantity: "22", product: Object) are not sent, my end-point thinking that array is empty. If I delete values from array in Vue object, then console.log looks fine but my end-poind doesn't see values in array.

Have anyone idea how to solve that?

Comment: Did you check what was sent over the network to see if it was actually sent to your endpoint?

Comment: Also, is your endpoint able to handle quantity being either a string or a number?

Comment: At the endpoint I getting: CreateOrderRequest(date=2020-02-02, buyerId=1, supplierId=1, orderDetails=[OrderDetailsDto(quantity=0, buyerSum=null, supplierSum=null, product=ProductDto(id=0, product=null), orderComment=null)])

Comment: orderDetails is supposed to be an array right?  Your v-model is setting the property "product" on orderDetails to the product object.  And it looks like you're setting "quantity" also as a property on orderDetails.

Comment: Are you maybe looking to set `v-model="orderDetails[0].product"`?  Or do you mean to be pushing/popping on the orderDetails array?

Comment: That's work! Thank so much! But here is one thing: that is hard-coded, what if I will want to add couple more orderDetails objects to that array?

Comment: Right, which is a different task.  You'll probably want something like a multiselect so you can both add and remove products you have added.

Comment: Or have orderDetails populate a list, with a remove button on each list item, and $emit an event or call a method that is received higher up to fill orderDetails properly every time you select a value.  A normal select with a v-model probably won't work for what you need.

Comment: Basicaly I'm making trade system to managing sales, could you advice me what should I learn to have possibility to adding many products to my orderDetails array? buyer and supplier will be same, but I want to display as many position with quantity and products as user will want. Sorry for noob questions but honestly I'm programming in Vue.js from 2 days and sometimes writting code is really frustating.. especially when you aren't sure what you want to ask..;D

Answer (score 0):

add `data: {currquantity:0, currproduct: {id: null, name: null}}`

```
           <div class="form-group">
                <label>Ilość (m3)</label>
                <input type="number" id="quantity" class="form-control" v-model="currproduct.quantity"/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Wybierz product</label>
                <select @change="order.orderDetails.push({quantity: currquantity, ...currproduct})" v-model="currproduct">
                <option
                    v-bind:value="{id: product.id, name: product.product}"
                    v-for="product in products"
                    v-bind:key="product.id"
                >{{ product.product }}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

You will probably want to create something like below to handle showing what has been added so far and ability to delete added items:

```
<ul>
<li v-for="(detail, i) in order.orderDetails">{{JSON.stringify(detail)}}
  <button @click="order.orderDetails.splice(i,1)">X</button>
</li>
</ul>
```